# Can't create user on Mac with dscl command

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, user-accounts

I was trying to create a postgres user using the command

```
sudo dscl . -create /Users/postgres
```

But failed. Got the following output

```
create: Invalid Path
<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14009 (eDSUnknownNodeName)
```

I had used dscl create and dscl delete commands prior to this failure.

```
sudo dscl . -create /Users/postgres
sudo dscl . -delete /Users/postgres
```

I think somehow I screwed up the system. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured out that there is was one plist file left. Had to delete

```
/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/postgres.plist
```

then creating user was successful.